# Deploying Azure Function Swagger API Definition using ARM

Tags: azure, swagger, azure-functions, openapi

We are creating an ARM template for our Azure Function that we would like to use for deploying to different environments however we cannot figure out how to deploy the Swagger with it.

As far as we see in the ARM template there is an option to add a link to the Swagger but can the Swagger be deployed as part of the ARM template itself?

Comment: I managed to do it using powershell script https://stackoverflow.com/a/50576113/4167200

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find any possible solution for it using only ARM templates?